# Can I use Big-O notation to compare performance of optimised and unoptimised implementation of same algorithm?

Tags: performance, sorting, big-o, complexity-theory

I'm writing about an optimisation about an algorithm which has O(n) complexity. It still has O(n) complexity but the execution time has improved tremendously. Is it correct for me to say that I've improved the O part? If not, how can I refer to the speed of the algorithm?

Comment: "how can I refer to the speed of the algorithm?" -- you just did that, didn't you? /s

Answer (score 3):

If you have only improved on the constant, you'll need to provide concrete timing statistics. Big-O notation is only for asymptotic behavior. For example, you'll need to specify a given set of test data, and show that your optimized version is X% or X times faster than the unoptimized version.

You have not improved the asymptotic behavior of the implementation, as both the original and the optimized version run in O(n) time.

Answer (score 0):

The complexity of the algorithm would have stayed the same, but you've reduced the runtime by a factor of x.  So for example, an 9001n^2 algorithm and an n^2 algorithm are both big O(n^2), but one is 9001 times faster.  Thus, going from the first to the second decreases the runtime by a factor of 9001.

Comment: How come the big O doesn't refer to this constant? Is there another variable that could?

Comment: Big O is for asymptotic notation, which basically means in this context "as it approaches infinity."  As n gets close to infinity, the difference between 9001n^2 and n^2 becomes miniscule, and thus they're treated the same in big O notation, because at that scale, the constant doesn't matter.  I don't think there's a formalized term on par with big O that includes constants, mainly because big O is used to show that algorithms are effective across all dataset sizes.

Answer (score 0):

O(n) = O(n), so no, you can't say anything about a change to the big-O complexity, since the big-O complexity didn't change.

You can simply say that the running time improved by a factor of X or by some percentage, or perhaps you could use [~-notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations).

Answer (score 0):

[This (deleted) question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25756686/103167) was a good example of optimization changing the asymptotic complexity.

It's not about sorting, but it does address the overall question you asked, so I'll reproduce the answer here, to give an example where optimization can be seen in Big-O notation:

---

TL;DR : Runtime needs to be measured, not "computed".

---

The runtime is HIGHLY compiler dependent.  I tested with three very popular C++ compilers under optimization level 2 and no whole program optimization.  One gave cubic runtime and two gave linear runtime.  Microsoft holds both best and worst places, depending on whether the amd64 or x86 compiler is used.

I ran using i = 1, 10, 100, 200, 1000, 2000, 10000, 20000 and enough iterations to take at least two seconds.  The times are reported against the frequency of my performance counter, not in seconds, but the timebase is steady so it's as good as any other.  This is a Core i5 Haswell if anyone cares.

Using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3, x86 compilation

```
timing unit is 2240908.000000 per second
i       iterations      elapsed time
1       1000000000      7974255
10      100000000       40455055
100     100000          30560052
200     10000           24365172
1000    100             30615626
2000    10              24530866
```

[image: cubic runtime from MSVC in 32-bit mode]

Using Visual Studio 2013 Update 3, x64 compilation

```
timing unit is 2240908.000000 per second
i       iterations      elapsed time
1       1000000000      6123844
10      1000000000      29860683
100     100000000       25790181
200     10000000        4977144
1000    10000000        23488811
2000    1000000         4750398
10000   1000000         23544227
20000   100000          4726392
```

Using cygwin g++ 4.8.2, 64-bit compilation

```
timing unit is 2240908.000000 per second
i       iterations      elapsed time
1       1000000000      6460830
10      1000000000      25768266
100     100000000       30732123
200     10000000        6294949
1000    10000000        31590581
2000    1000000         6206729
10000   1000000         31528696
20000   100000          6217971
```

[image: linear runtime from both 64-bit compilers]

Here's the benchmark driver:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

extern long long the_function(int i);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    LARGE_INTEGER timing_freq;
    QueryPerformanceFrequency(&timing_freq);
    printf("timing unit is %f per second\n", (double)timing_freq.QuadPart);

    for( int a = 1; a < argc; ++a ) {
        char* pEnd;
        int i = strtoul(argv[a], &pEnd, 0);
        if (*pEnd) {
            printf("Couldn't understand \'%s\'\n", argv[a]);
            return 1;
        }

        LARGE_INTEGER before;
        LARGE_INTEGER after;
        long long iterations = 1;
        do {
            iterations *= 10;
            QueryPerformanceCounter(&before);
            for( int k = 0; k < iterations; ++k )
                the_function(i);

            QueryPerformanceCounter(&after);
        } while (after.QuadPart - before.QuadPart < 2 * timing_freq.QuadPart);

        printf("%d\t%lld\t%lld\n", i, iterations, after.QuadPart - before.QuadPart);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

And the code being evaluated:

```
long long the_function(int i)
{
    long long x = 0;
    for(int n = 0; n < i; n++)
        for (int j = 0; j < n*n; j++)
            x++;
    return x;
}
```